# Alternative to function sendToHost() that will handle https

Tags: php, https, ping

I've been using a function called sendToHost that has worked for pinging a server with a GET string and returning a response.

```
#  Example of GET string:
#  sub.domain.com/api.php?a=1&b=2&c=3
$var = sendToHost('sub.domain.com','get','/api.php','a=1&b=2&c=3');
```

However it won't handle sending to a Secure Server (https).

Does anyone know of a php function alternative to sendToHost?

Here's the SendToHost code:

```
/* sendToHost
 * ~~~~~~~~~~
 * Params:
 *   $host - Just the hostname.  No http:// or /path/to/file.html portions
 *   $method - get or post, case-insensitive
 *   $path - The /path/to/file.html part
 *   $data - The query string, without initial question mark
 *   $useragent - If true, 'MSIE' will be sent as the User-Agent (optional)
 *
 * Examples:
 *   sendToHost('www.google.com','get','/search','q=php_imlib');
 *   sendToHost('www.example.com','post','/some_script.cgi',
 *              'param=First+Param&second=Second+param');
 */
function sendToHost($host,$method,$path,$data,$useragent=0)
{
    // Supply a default method of GET if the one passed was empty
    if (empty($method))
        $method = 'GET';
    $method = strtoupper($method);
    $fp = fsockopen($host,80);
    if ($method == 'GET')
        $path .= '?' . $data;
    fputs($fp, "$method $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    if ($method == 'POST')
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n");
    if ($useragent)
        fputs($fp, "User-Agent: MSIE\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    if ($method == 'POST')
        fputs($fp, $data);

    while (!feof($fp))
        $buf .= fgets($fp,128);
    fclose($fp);
    return $buf;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using curl? It supports ssl and works well under GNU/Linux..

Comment: Two useful functions along these lines can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#98628